# Using Vim, how do I 'set statusline' to align right?

Tags: vim

My `~/.vimrc` uses the following statusline setting

```
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\ %{&ff}\ %Y\ [0x\%02.2B]\ %l/%L,%v\ %p%%
```

Everything is left aligned. `help 'statusline'` says that the `-` character is used to "Left justify the item.  The default is right justified when minwid is larger than the length of the item."

However, I haven't been able to use (or not use) `-` to ever align things to the right.

What is an example of having one group of items left aligned and one group right aligned?

I've also tried to use `=` but it just prints the `=` sign.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to prefix the `=` with a percent sign: `%=`.

Using your example:

```
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\ %{&ff}\ %Y\ [0x\%02.2B]\ %=l/%L,%v\ %p%%
```

Will right-align the "`%l/%L,%v\ %p%%`" group. You should also probably force a truncation using `%<` in a suitable place to accommodate narrow windows:

```
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w%<\ %{&ff}\ %Y\ [0x\%02.2B]\ %=l/%L,%v\ %p%%
```

Comment: `%=%l` because I want the current line number

Answer (score 6):

You must use `%=`

What is at the left of `%=` will be left aligned, and what is at the right of `%=` will be right aligned.

For example, here is the statusline I use.

`set statusline=%f%m%r%h\ [%L]\ [%{&ff}]\ %y%=[%p%%]\ [line:%05l,col:%02v]`

Answer (score 1):

Agree with [Xavier T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513198/xavier-t).

using `%=` which means right-align following items

The fallowing is my vimrc

`set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\ [FORMAT=%{&ff}][TYPE=%Y][ASCII=\%03.3b][HEX=\%02.2B]%=[POS=%04l,%04v][%p%%][LEN=%L]`